# use mount with LUKS2

Tags: mount, luks, device-mapper

Back in times of LUKS1, it was possible to use a command like

```
$ mount /dev/luks-encrypted-partition /mnt/a 
[enter passphrase upon being prompted]
```

as a shortcut for

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/luks-encrypted-partition some-name
$ mount /dev/mapper/some-name /mnt/a
```

But since LUKS2 this ability is lost. Directly trying to mount a LUKS2 encrypted partition results in the following error message:

```
$ mount /dev/luks-encrypted-partition /mnt/a
mount: /mnt/a: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
```

Does anyone know how I can get back to the old functionality?
I am using an up-to-date Arch Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic mounting of encrypted partition is possible by helper program *mount.crypt*, which is part of *libpam_mount_bin* package. The support for LUKS2 in *libpam_mount* was introduced in version *libpam-mount-2.16-5ubuntu0.1* in 2019 (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-mount/+bug/1804408 ).

So, the error you encounter is not due to lack of LUKS2 support. I had similar problem after upgrade of (K)ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 probably because helper program *mount.crypt* and symlinks *mount.crypt_LUKS* and *mount.crypto_LUKS* are now part of ***libpam-mount-bin*** package and **not *libpam-mount***, and this package was not installed during upgrade. The hint about package change comes from https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=324991 .

Check if you have the mount helper program installed.